# MyAssembly.XmlSerializers.dll cannot be loaded while debugging (FileNotFound)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

My program is using Xml Serialization and it worked fine up to a certain point.
But then I get:

> The Assembly ... "MyAssembly.XmlSerializers" could not be loaded in
>   the "LoadFrom" binding context ... System.IO.FileNotFoundException

After a long search for the reason I found out that it failed after I had activated the
"Managed Debugging Assistants". Whenever the "BindingFailure" checkbox is activated, the error comes. When the checkbox is deactivated, the program and the XmlSerialization work fine.

This is the full text of the error message:

> *Der Assistent für verwaltetes Debugging ""BindingFailure"" hat ein Problem in
>   ""C:\sh\KisWien\ResultsWien_ByWSClient\R2EMSUNITTEST2\R2EMSUNITTEST\bin\Debug\R2MTest_EMS_UNITTEST_EMS_CDA__Exe.vshost.exe""
>   festgestellt. Zusätzliche Informationen: Die Assembly mit dem
>   Anzeigenamen "R2EMS_EpidemiologieMeldungByCDA.XmlSerializers" konnte
>   im "LoadFrom"-Bindungskontext der AppDomain mit ID 1 nicht geladen
>   werden. Fehlerursache: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder
>   Assembly "R2EMS_EpidemiologieMeldungByCDA.XmlSerializers,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" oder eine
>   Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die
>   angegebene Datei nicht finden.*

Deactivating ""BindingFailure"" solved the problem.

However I was not able to create volontarly the xxxx.XmlSerializers.dll, even when setting the Project Option 'Create Serializer assembly' to ON.
Does somebody know the trick to get the serializer assembly?